# ASP.NET Core Web API - Cannot implicitly convert type 'Response<LoginResponseDto>' to 'Response<bool>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am implementing User Authentication using Identity DB Context and Entity Framework in In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Guid RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Dto:**

```
public class RegisterUserDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResponseDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public Guid RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

public class LoginDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**AuthenticationService:**

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ITokenGeneratorService _tokenGenerator;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AuthenticationService(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger logger,
        IMapper mapper, ITokenGeneratorService tokenGenerator)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;

    }

    private async Task<Response<bool>> ValidateUser(LoginDto model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        var response = new Response<bool>();
        if (user == null)
        {
            var registerModel = new RegisterUserDto
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                UserName = model.Email,
                Password = model.Password,
            };
           var  resgistration = await Register(registerModel);
            if(resgistration.Succeeded)
            {
                var token = _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user);
                _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
            }
            return Login(model);
         }
        if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            response.Message = "Invalid Credentials";
            response.Succeeded = false;
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return response;
        }
        if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user) && user.IsActive)
        {
            response.Message = "Account not activated";
            response.Succeeded = false;
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            response.Succeeded = true;
            return response;
        }
    }

    public async Task<Response<LoginResponseDto>> Login(LoginDto model)
    {
        var response = new Response<LoginResponseDto>();
        var validityResult = await ValidateUser(model);

        if (!validityResult.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.Error("Login operation failed");
            response.Message = validityResult.Message;
            response.StatusCode = validityResult.StatusCode;
            response.Succeeded = false;
            return response;
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        var refreshToken = _tokenGenerator.GenerateRefreshToken();
        user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
        user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        var result = new LoginResponseDto()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Token = await _tokenGenerator.GenerateToken(user),
            RefreshToken = refreshToken
        };

        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        _logger.Information("User successfully logged in");
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Message = "Login Successfully";
        response.Data = result;
        response.Succeeded = true;
        return response;
    }

    public async Task<Response<string>> Register(RegisterUserDto model)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);
        user.IsActive = true;
        var response = new Response<string>();
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Customer);
                var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var encodedToken = TokenConverter.EncodeToken(token);
                var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                var customer = new Customer
                {
                    AppUser = user
                };
                await _unitOfWork.Customers.InsertAsync(customer);
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                response.Succeeded = true;
                response.Data = user.Id;
                response.Message = "User created successfully!";
                transaction.Complete();
                return response;
            }
            response.Message = GetErrors(result);
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            response.Succeeded = false;
            transaction.Complete();
            return response;
        };
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

At login, I want to use ValidateUser to checks if user exists or not. If the user doesn't exist it should register it, validate it's email and re-login to it properly.

I got this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Response<LoginResponseDto>' to 'Response<bool>'
```

Then, **return Login(model)** is highlighted in:

```
private async Task<Response<bool>> ValidateUser(LoginDto model)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The message is quite clear. `Login` function returns `Response<LoginResponseDto>`. You can't directly use it to return in the `ValidateUser` function. I believe that you can do like extract the properties' value returned from the `Login` function and assign to the new `Response<bool>` instance. But I feel like something weird in your approach, it looks like violates the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: @YongShun - Can you give an alternative way of doing it or Can you give example from my code how I can correct the current code